# Installed Cinnamon on Ubuntu. Is it considered Linux Mint or Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-environments

I installed Cinnamon on my Ubuntu OS.  Am I still using Ubuntu or Linux Mint when I use the Cinnamon desktop environment?

Comment: Simple answer : You wont become Pilot even you have pilot clothes on you because you are not Pilot in real. Similarly Ubuntu is not Linux Mint even you install its DE. :)

Comment: You'll find out at the next upgrade! I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 +XFCE.  This was upgraded from 12.04+XFCE.  It's less XFCE-like (e.g. login screen) than it was before I updated and there are some quirks which aren't an issue in my Xubuntu system (another machine).  My situation  isn't exactly parallel but is indicative.

Comment: then install GNOME and it'll turn into fedora.

Answer (score 13):

Ubuntu with a Cinnamon desktop environment is still considered Ubuntu: a Linux distribution is far more than just a desktop environment. Distributions differ by several default packages. For instance, since 15.04 Ubuntu is switching to another init system, which brings up services. Mint as far as I know, on the other hand, is still using upstart.

Comment: here's more info : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83907/85039

Answer (score 6):

Cinnamon on Ubuntu is still Ubuntu - it's just a desktop environment.

It's on topic here as well.

My pronouns are He / Him

Answer (score 5):

You're still using Ubuntu, with a different [DE](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_environment).