# Open Bangla or avro phonetic not work on Ubuntu 21.10 cinnamon

Tags: application-development, cinnamon, ibus, 21.10, ibus-avro

I have upgraded ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10 and it is found that avro phonetic bangla or open Bangla is not working on cinnaman but works fine in ubuntu, how can I install avro bangla or open bangla in cinnaman/

Comment: I guess [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633462/installed-cinnamon-on-ubuntu-is-it-considered-linux-mint-or-ubuntu#633466) about Cinnamon still applies - so on topic for clarity. Removed `Debian` tag

Comment: What all steps have you tried? `not working on cinnaman but works fine in ubuntu` -- Are they the same installation? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1374114/edit) the question to add these information.